# How do I write an rsync exclude for a directory tree with names containing spaces?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, rsync, exclude

I'm trying to exclude a directory tree as part of an `rsync` command embedded in a `bash` script approximately like this:

```
$OPTIONS="-rl --exclude 'Some Parent Directory/Another Directory'"

rsync $OPTIONS $SOURCEDIR a@b.com:/SomeTargetDir
```

My aim is to sync all of `$SOURCEDIR` into `/SomeTargetDir` on the target machine, with the exception of everything under `Some Parent Directory/Another Directory`. However, I keep seeing errors of this form:

```
rsync: link_stat "/Users/myusername/Parent\" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I assume this is related to escaping the exclude path, but I just can't seem to get it right: every combination of `\\`, `\` and so on that I try doesn't seem right. How can I write the exclude rule correctly?

I don't want to use `--exclude-from` unless I absolutely have to.

I am using rsync version 3.0.9 on OS X 10.8, syncing to Ubuntu 12.04 over SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude matches patterns too. So try it like this:

```
$OPTIONS="-rl --exclude '*/Another Directory'"
rsync $OPTIONS $SOURCEDIR a@b.com:/SomeTargetDir
```

See this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/) for more details.

#### EDIT #1

Another suggestion would be to try escaping double quotes rather than use single quotes:

```
$OPTIONS="-rl --exclude \"Some Parent\ Directory/Another\ Directory\""
```

The OP tried this alternative but it still didn't work for him in his case. It does work for me on Linux using version "3.0.8  protocol version 30" of `rsync`.

Comment: Thanks. That's not really what I wanted, though; I wanted to exclude only that specific subdirectory - 'Some Parent Directory/Another Directory'.

Comment: it will also exclude `Different Parent Directory/Another Directory`, which isn't what I'm asking for.

Comment: I cannot use double-quotes, as the environment variable in question (`$OPTIONS`) is already double-quoted.

Comment: Good point, sorry. Nevertheless, I've just tried this and I still see the same error as before.

Comment: What version of rsync are you using on MacOSX? Also can you show a little more of the directory tree, when I use the commands as I've suggested they work for me. Running `rsync --version` shows mine to be "3.0.8  protocol version 30".

Answer (score 1):

Use `--exclude-from`.
The exclusion file will have all patterns on a new line, and you can forget about quotes, escaping and space problems.

I have a similar script to yours, and this is what I did.
Note that with this solution, I am generating the exclusion file in my script, therefore I still have to make sure quotes are right. If you can have a static exclusion file, that will be even simpler.

```
# create a temporary file
RSYNC_EXCLUDES=$( mktemp -t rsync-excludes )
# remove the temp file when the script exits
trap "rm -f $RSYNC_EXCLUDES" EXIT
# populate the exclusion file
echo 'Some Parent Directory/Another Directory' > "$RSYNC_EXCLUDES"
# have your options point to your exclusion file
$OPTIONS="-rl --exclude-from='$RSYNC_EXCLUDES'"
# profit
rsync $OPTIONS $SOURCEDIR a@b.com:/SomeTargetDir
```